# Trouble Installing Composer on Windows 7

Tags: installation, xampp

Man oh man. I've looked everywhere for help, done everything I could, and now I'm here because I am simply stumped. I wasn't sure whether to ask this question here, or on Stackoverflow, but I assumed it would be here based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403007/trying-to-install-composer

So here is the issue. I have a little xampp server running locally. I am working with some extensions for Mediawiki that need composer to install. Originally, I purposely bought a host that allowed me shell access so that I could do it there, but it seems my ISP blocks me from using SSH at all (it would time out). To get around the issue, I decided to try and run a server locally and just transfer the database when I was finished.

I first downloaded the installer for Windows available on the composer website

Everything works all fine and well until it's actually time to download the files

```
    Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org

    Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
    Failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the 
    connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
    established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

So I stopped and did a little research. I came across some posts explaining that maybe openssl in the xampp php.ini wasn't enabled. I went through and checked and it was indeed enabled. I read that there might be more than one php.ini, one in the php folder and one in the apache folder, but my version only has one php.ini.

After failing to use the automatic installer, I decided to try it manually (from here: https://getcomposer.org/download/ ). I downloaded the composer.phar file and placed it into the php folder. I also created the composer.bat file as instructed. At this point I became stuck again, as the "composer -" or "composer --version" still wasn't working (said that the command didn't exist)

I started over and attempted to follow the instructions word for word by using the shell and downloading it that way instead of manually. Sadly, I ran into yet another error, similar to the one I ran into with the installer.

```
    Warning: readfile(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to 
    open  stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected 
    party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
    established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

At this point, I'm kind of pulling my hair out because I'm not sure why my requests aren't getting through. I did some more research and I saw posts speaking about how you might run into this error if you are doing it from a proxy, but to my knowledge, I am not behind a proxy. I even double tripled checked just to be sure I wasn't insane by using the everyday "am I behind a proxy" site. I pinged the websites from the shell and it had no problem finding it. I saw that you can try without using https and just using http, but that didn't work either.

I did some more digging and saw that the composer.phar had a diagnose option, so I ran it through:

```
    $ php composer.phar diagnose
    Checking composer.json: FAIL
    name : is missing and it is required
    description : is missing and it is required
    No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you
    may use "proprietary" as license.
    Checking platform settings: OK
    Checking git settings: OK
    Checking http connectivity: FAIL
    [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org
    /packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: 
    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
    properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
    failed because connected host has failed to respond.

    Checking disk free space: OK
    Checking composer version:

    [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
    The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: 
    failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the 
    connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
    established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

    diagnose
```

So now I'm wondering, could it be that something on my computer, a setting, a program, something else, is blocking me from using shell in this way? First I couldn't use SSH, now I'm having trouble using it even locally... I'm just really looking for a solution.

I have Avast installed for my antivirus (which I disabled in an attempt to get things going, but no dice) I use Private Firewall for my firewall, but I don't have it running right now. Is there just some small detail that has completely gone over my head? I don't know. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem when installing composer setup file on Win8. Disabled a private firewall, and click Retry under the error message. It went right through and installed correctly.